# How to remove the content in the variable using perl

Tags: regex, perl

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
print "Please enter the number";
chomp($inNum =<>);
if($inNum =~ /^[0]+/)
{

 print "The length is ",length($inNum),"\n";
 print  " Trailing Zero's  present","\n";
 $inNum =~ s/^[0]+/  /; 
 print  "The new output is" , $inNum ,"\n"; 
 print "The new length is ",length($inNum),"\n";

 }
 else
 {
  print "The input format vaild";
 }
```

output

Please enter the number :000010

The length is : 6

Trailing Zero's present

The new output is 10

The new length is :4

Issue is  with the new length value which should be (2) but it is displaying (4)
How to solve this issue ?

Comment: `if($inNum =~ /^[0]+/)` could be simplified to `if ($inNum =~ /^0/)`.  The brackets `[]` are superfluous in both regular expressions

Comment: ps the plural of `zero` is `zeroes`, not `zero's`.

Comment: pps "trailing" is something that comes after, not before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're replacing the four 0s with 2 space characters.  Try this.

```
$inNum =~ s/^[0]+//;
```

Answer (score 4):

You want `s/^0+//`, not `s/^[0]+/  /`.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';

print 'Please enter the number: ';
chomp(my $inNum = <>);
if ($inNum =~ /^0+/) {  # has padding zeroes
    printf "The length is <%d>.\n", length($inNum);
    print "Padding zeroes present.\n";
    $inNum =~ s/^0+/  /; # replace any padding zeroes with two spaces
    printf "The new output is <%s>.\n", $inNum;
    printf "The new length is <%d>.\n", length($inNum);
} else {
    print "The input format was invalid.\n";
}
```

---

```
Please enter the number: 000010
The length is <6>.
Padding zeroes present.
The new output is <  10>.
The new length is <4>.
```

Answer (score 2):

yea you are replacing with white spaces, still if you dont want to change your reg expressions you could add a sub

> > ```
> > sub trim($) {   
> > my $string = shift;   
> > $string =~ s/^\s+//;  
> > $string =~ s/\s+$//;      
> > return $string;
> > ```
> >
> > }

and use

```
print "The new length is ",length(trim($inNum)),"\n";
```

Comment: This works, but it seems rather dumb to print the length of a trimmed string rather than trim the actual string. Why wouldn't the OP want to change an incorrect regex?

Comment: I know, just wanted to offer a different option for different scenarios, as in my company sometimes we store values a number and as string depending on our needs.

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to strip leading zeros, you might consider using [sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) instead of a regex.

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Please enter the number: ";
my $num = sprintf "%d", scalar <>;
say "$num";
```

Be aware that if you do not enter a number, you will get a warning.

Comment: @shawn `my $num |= 0`. All you really need is to refer to the number with some function that converts the string to a number.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print "Please enter the number";
my $num = 0 + <>;
print "The number is '$num'\n";

__END__
```